# The focus is not moved on the top of the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I am using update panel and pagination links by repeater control at the bottom of the page. Now when we click on pagination links, the page is not focused on the top of the page. I have tried the folllowing jquery code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#<%=rptPager.ClientID %> a").click(function () {
        parent.window.scrollTo(0, 0);
    });
    });
 </script>
```

but it doesnot work... Please help me!!!

Answer (score 0):

i think you were looking for `window.scrollTo(0, 0);`

`parent.window.scrollTo(0, 0);` won't work in your code, since `parent` will be undefined.

`this.parent` however, would point to the parent of the element you clicked.